Rasterio affine transform pixel size meaning
I'm using calculate_default_transform and reproject from rasterio.warp to transform geotiff file from one coordinate reference system (EPSG:25832) to another (EPSG:3857). As a result the pixel size increases 1.78 times (from 1.00m to 1.78m). However the width and height of the file don't decrease at all, they only seem to change due to the rotation of the file. Shouldn't both the width and height decrease 1.78 times, since the pixel size increases 1.78 times?
The metadata of the input file:
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': -9999.0, 'width': 174, 'height': 103, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(25832), 'transform': Affine(1.000576604934724, 0.0, 720913.5009167447,0.0, -1.000576604934724, 6198161.762995626)}
The metadata of the output file:
Meta out: {'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': -9999.0, 'width': 179, 'height': 112, 'count': 1, 'crs': 'EPSG:3857', 'transform': Affine(1.7803843253550649, 0.0, 1395028.4779017419,0.0, -1.7803843253550649, 7534204.142989517)}
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
from rasterio.warp import reproject, calculate_default_transform

def transform_geotiff(input_file, output_file, target_crs='EPSG:3857'):
    """
    Transforms a GeoTIFF file from its original CRS to a target CRS.

    Args:
    input_file (str): Path to the input GeoTIFF file.
    output_file (str): Path where the transformed file will be saved.
    target_crs (str): The target CRS
    """

    with rasterio.open(input_file) as src:
        transform, width, height = calculate_default_transform(
            src.crs, target_crs, src.width, src.height, *src.bounds)
        kwargs = src.meta.copy()
        print('Meta in:', src.meta)
        kwargs.update({
            'crs': target_crs,
            'transform': transform,
            'width': width,
            'height': height
        })

        with rasterio.open(output_file, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
                reproject(
                    source=rasterio.band(src, i),
                    destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                    src_transform=src.transform,
                    src_crs=src.crs,
                    dst_transform=transform,
                    dst_crs=target_crs,
                    resampling=Resampling.nearest)


In EPSG:3857 the meters are longer, despite over the equator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection. If you want to get 1m pixels, use parameter -resolution https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.warp.html.

EPSG:3857 distorts distance. It's designed for web maps and shouldn't be used for anything other than visualisation.

@user2856 So you could say that pixel size has no direct physical meaning except in the local CRS of the country where the LIDAR data (geotiff) was measured?
